# HttpClient Response Message Size

Tags: httpclient, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi

```
public ISearchProviderCommandResult ExecuteCommand(ISearchProviderCommand searchCommand)
{
  //serialize the object before sending it in
  JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  string jsonInput = serializer.Serialize(searchCommand);

  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(ServiceUrl), MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000 };

  StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonInput, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

  HttpResponseMessage output = httpClient.PostAsync(ServiceUrl, content).Result;

  //deserialize the output of the webapi call
  SearchProviderCommandResult searchResult = serializer.Deserialize<SearchProviderCommandResult>(output.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

  return searchResult;
}
```

on my local machine whether I set the MaxResponseContentBufferSize  or not, it seems to retrieve data the way I want it.  However on our build environment, If I dont set the MaxResponseContentBufferSize , I get this error:
Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 65536.

After looking on google, I decided to set the MaxResponseContentBufferSize to an arbitrary 256000 value. Even though this works on my local machine, on the build box I get this error:
Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.HttpClient.set_MaxResponseContentBufferSize(Int64)

I have no idea what to do now.

Comment: What is this code for? For an ASP.NET application or any other?

Comment: yes, its asp.net web api code. we solved it based on my comments in Anand's post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this thread on [forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1792578.aspx/1). It seems there is some issue with .net 4.5 beta version on your build environment. There is surely a mismatch of dlls on your local and your build environment

Comment: Thats exactly what we did based on this forum post:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/743315/system-missingmethodexception-when-using-httpclient-maxresponsecontentbuffersize - However thanks for your post too.